# mysql JSON arrays returned as string

Tags: mysql, node.js

hi im trying to read a json array returned by mysql, but it returns a string instead.

```js
mysql.getConnection((err, con) => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM guild WHERE ID = "1" LIMIT 1`, (err, guild) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(guild)
  })
})
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You mean one of the columns in the table is a JSON datatype? I think it's normal for that to be returned as a string, you need to call `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert strings to Objects or Arrays with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). You also can reverse this operation with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Here's your code with these minor changes.

```js
mysql.getConnection((err, con) => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM guild WHERE ID = "1" LIMIT 1`, (err, guildStr) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    const guild = JSON.parse(guildStr)
    console.log(guild)
  })
})
```